# Is there a way to show only images selection on google recaptcha?

Tags: google, recaptcha

My client wants to show only images selection on google recaptcha. He thinks only clicking a checkbox is not secure.

Comment: This link explains the different captchas: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions - sounds like you would need v3?

Comment: It might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42017259/4155637